# MVP with Rx is same as MVVM or not

Tags: android, architecture

In the case of MVP, the Presenter holds a view object. While in the case of MVVM, VM does not hold View object because view updated via data binding/live data. I want to know that if I use RxJava/Data binding in the case of MVP then no need to hold view object by the presenter. Now there is any diff in MVP and MVVM? Any valuable suggestions, please?

One clear diff I can see is that in the case of MVVM, VM holds data while activity recreated. While there is no such advantage in MVP.

https://medium.com/@prajvalprabhakar/mvp-vs-mvvm-93657494106b
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidArchitecture/article.html

Answer (score 0):

i think no if we use rx with mvp than we can say its reactive programing but not exactly mvvm becuase if we see mvvm arch. it's not only include reactive things or live data its also  include data biniding and many more and yes main thing it's also use repository concepts for data call (API + local), thats why we can not say that mvp with rx its same as mvvm

Comment: I think repository is plain java class that make api call or database call. I can add that one in MVP.